# Facebook sdk 3.0 with iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

I have been making iOS apps for a while now and am pretty comfortable with that. What I haven't done is add Facebook connectivity in any of my apps.

What I am looking today is for a tutorial of how to integrate Facebook SDK 3.0 with iOS 5.0 running with Xcode 4.2. During my research i found that 3.0 was compatible with Xcode 4.2. I am not ready to move onto iOS 6.0 and Xcode 4.5 just yet.

So my question is there any tutorial out there that can give me step by step instructions of how to integrate Facebook skd 3.0 with iOS 5 running on Xcode 4.2?

I have been looking for a tutorial for those specifications; all I find are tutorials and instructions for iOS 6 and Facebook SDK 3.1.

What I am able to do so far is

- Download Facebook SDK 3.0 from this link http://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/
- I signed up on Facebook developer account and create a sample project AppID
- I tried compiling a brand new Xcode project with Facebook sdk but that's where I started to run into issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial shows how to integrate Facebook SDK 3.0 to upload statutes and post pictures to users walls. Hope this helps :http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html

You can retrieve the birthdays of your (or the user's) facebook friends with a single fql request.

You can read about fql here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

But here's some code for reference (this code is in a class defined to be a FBSessionDelegate, and FBRequestDelegate)

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    // result is a NSDictionary of your friends and their birthdays!
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    //some best practice boiler plate code for storing important stuff from fb
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    //now load all my friend's birthdays
    NSMutableDictionary * params = 
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"select birthday, name, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name", 
                         @"query",
                         nil];

    [self.facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" andParams: params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: self];
}

- (void) loginWithFacebook {
    self.facebook = [[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"<your app id here>" andDelegate:self] autorelease];
    //IMPORTANT - you need to ask for permission for friend's birthdays
    [facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"friends_birthday"]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks MacNoob. That is definitely more informative than what I had been goggling. One more question do you know of any Facebook iOS tutorial where I can connect to users account and get their friends birthdays? I need this for an iOS app that I am making

Comment: Actually this code does not work with Facebook SDK 3.0. I had to google that up and write it differently. Got it here from Facebook website itself http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/. Still thank you for pointing me to the right tutorial! Working like a charm